# glutInit() Throws an Error - Cannot find DLL

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, opengl

I'm currently building an application in C#, using a basic design I came up with in VB.net for applications involving openGL. Using the Tao framework in VB, I have the following method:

```
Private Sub checkForGlutInit()
    If glut_initialized = False Then
        Glut.glutInit()
        glut_initialized = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This method is called during Form1.Load and thus allows the program to initialize all the GL variables before trying to draw anything. Everything runs perfectly. I then translated all of the same code over to C sharp to begin a new application.

```
private void checkForGlutInit()
{
    if (glut_initialized == false)
    {
        Glut.glutInit();
        glut_initialized = true;
    }
}
```

When this method in C sharp gets called, it makes the call to Glut.glutInit(), but the method then terminates with an error, telling me that the DLL cannot be found. I've duplicated the environment settings (compiling x86 code, copying the DLLs to both the Debug and Release directories), but I'm still getting the error.

Is there something about C sharp that manages DLLs differently than VB? If not, is there something that I may be missing about referencing the DLL 'freeglut'?

Answer (score 0):

Try coping freeglut dlls to both Windows/SysWoW64 and Windows/System32.
It should help if its problem with freeglut dll.